# What does "Stable-ish" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have recently heard in a Tv show that some guy said:

> He is stable-ish for now!

What does this term mean exactly? couldn't find anything, what's the occasion to use? can we use the -ish suffix for any adjective?

Comment: The -ish suffix can be appended to adjectives to postmodify them. This may give rise to a totally acceptable word (reddish, coolish, fairish), a word that has an obvious meaning but is not really established (stable-ish) or something more or less outlandish (wise-ish, outlandishish). It has very nearly the same effect as inserting the premodifier 'fairly' - so 'stable-ish' is a quirky alternative for 'fairly stable'. With the suffix, there is a connotation that the downtoning is a hedging afterthought.

Comment: This very informal and is not at all recommended for writing.

Comment: Wow, why all the close votes? This particular usage of '-ish' is very new so not gen ref at all.

Comment: @Mitch: The usage is not new - this is a new example. Here's a newer one: fiendishish (though where the accepted word - non-word divide occurs for any given space-time-social grouping coordinates occurs for a particular string is obviously rather vauge).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

-ish

> 1) A suffix that makes any word or phrase more vague.
>
> 2) It can be used with any word and it's applied at the end to make the word into meaning "kind of".

For eg.

> me = "how are you feeling today?"
>
> you = "i am feeling okay-ish"

More

> 3) A suffix used to guesstimate a number or time. When referring to time "-ish" means within plus or minus 15 minutes. When referring to a number "-ish" means within 5.

For eg.

> Guy1: What time is the party?
>
> Guy2: 7:30-ish

Other definition:

> 4) suffix. used to describe an approximation, or likeness of the subject. (can be used alone as an adjective)

So, here the meaning of the stable-ish to he is okay-okay or not good not bad..

Update reference by the request of @trevorD

[The term = ish](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=-ish)

Comment: Are these definitions quoted from a dictionary or similar? If so, please provide links to the sources as others do and as requested in the Help info.

Comment: @TrevorD..I updated the reference.

Comment: Apart from the time, more or less identical to my post, no? Also spelling: "vague". "okay-okay" is not an English idiom and Urban dictionary is not a serious reference

Comment: Doesn't 'vauge' mean vague-ish?

Comment: No. Not according to the excellent Urban Dictionary reference: _vauge. spanish word for vagina._

Comment: **dictionary**   

Noun
A book that lists the words of a language... [Google?] ... 'misnomer' is a word springing to mind.

Comment: @mplungjan..do you like urban dictionary or not? sometime you said it's not serious reference in the next comment you said excellent? it gives me right hint then I use it as simple as that.. if my answer is wrong then tell me? don't downvote me.

Comment: Perhaps some would call UD a dictionaryish.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth..yes you are right it give me right answer then it is a good reference..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth..lol good man. I think you inspired by this post via frequently using -ish :P

Comment: @Java D: Ay, there's the rubb.

Comment: a) Yes I like and use Urban Dictionary to enlighten myself about words used in slang and often not yet in established dictionaries b) I have learned not to link UD as a reference here, because it is not a proper dictionary. c) if the word you are looking for exists in any of the established dictionaries and have the same meaning, quote the established dictionary. My downvote is mainly based on spelling, poor choice of reference and childish irritation that you chose to post an answer that repeats what I posted with the addition of the time reference that could be inferred from my post too

Comment: @mplungjan.. no man no when I writing the answer at that time your answer is posted within the minute both answers are posted.. so I don't know that you give it already..

Answer (score 9):

It means more or less stable

[dictionary.reference.com:  -ish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ish)

> a suffix used to form adjectives from other adjectives, with the sense of “somewhat,” “rather” ( oldish; reddish; sweetish )

You can add -ish to most anything and a (British) native speaker will understand it means more or less of what you added it to.

That goes for time: *five thirty-ish*;  and age: *She looks 40ish*

In spoken English, you add a slight pause to emphasise it and you can even use the suffix on its own

> "Are you OK?"
>   "yeah... ish"

meaning I am more or less OK